# Convert a 32768kb EGA file into a 256x256 Texture2D?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, graphics, xna

I'm sorry this is sort of a helps-noone-but-the-original-poster kind of question, but I'm trying to convert Ultima 4's SHAPES.EGA into a Texture2D. Each byte in SHAPES.EGA represents 2 pixels, and there are 256 16x16 graphics. I need to get them in a square because XNA's Reach profile doesn't support an image dimension higher than 2048, regardless of the actual image size. The following code gets me what I want for the first row, but but all further rows do not work correctly. (Assuming it continued this pattern, the 17th row would look like how the 2nd row should look.) I've been working on this for hours and I've got nothing at this point.

```
int cur_size = 16;

GFX.SHAPES_EGA = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, cur_size * 16, cur_size * 16);
Color[] temparray = new Color[(cur_size * 16) * (cur_size * 16)];

int CurrentIndex = 0, foo;
for (int Vertical = 0; Vertical < cur_size * 16; Vertical++) //16
{
    for (int Horizontal = 0; Horizontal < 16; Horizontal++)
    {
        for (int CurByte = 0; CurByte < 8; CurByte++)
        {
            //foo = (Vertical * (cur_size / 2)) + (Horizontal * 8 * cur_size) + CurByte;
            foo = (Vertical * (cur_size / 2)) + (Horizontal * 8 * cur_size) + CurByte;
            //Console.WriteLine((CurrentIndex * 2) + "+" + foo);
            temparray[(CurrentIndex*2)] = Basic.EgaToColor((File_SHAPES_EGA[foo] >> 4) & 0x0F);
            temparray[(CurrentIndex*2) + 1] = Basic.EgaToColor(File_SHAPES_EGA[foo] & 0x0F);
            CurrentIndex++;
        }
    }
}
GFX.SHAPES_EGA.SetData(temparray);
```

[image: The image demonstrates that the image loading code is bugged.]

Comment: Might be more appropriate on "code review".

Comment: @pst You're definitely right.

Comment: Where is "cur_size" set in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Vertical++` try `Vertical += 16`. Thumbs up for Ultima!

Comment: I'm sorry, my codebase changed so much since I asked this and I haven't touched it in so long I have no clue if this is correct.